# This release includes permissions that haven't been declared in Play Console. Go to Sensitive app permissions to update your permission declarations

Tags: android, react-native

My react native app is being rejected in the google play store for the reason that it requests background location of which my app does not request for user location weather foreground or background. And i can't find location access declaration in my app even after i ran `expo eject` no location permission declared in my `manifest.xml`.

How can i tell google that my app does not request user location.

Comment: check you installed packages on the apps project, I had the same, to only discover that one of the packages (expo-notifications) in my case was using the location data